# Update the value of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to change the value of `cost` in `itemToReplaceFirst` but it is not be updated by adding `itemsecond.cost + 1000` .

```js
let MyArray =  [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "CostInfo": [
      {"cost": 1000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 4000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 1000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 2000}
    ]
  }
]

let itemToReplaceFirst = MyArray.map((item) => {
  let itemToReplaceSecond = item.CostInfo.map((itemsecond) => {
    return { ...itemsecond, cost: itemsecond.cost + 1000 };
  });

  return  item
});

console.log(itemToReplaceFirst)
```

Comment: You're doing nothing with `itemToReplaceSecond`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Not Really, this is not intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are the boundaries of your problem is, but you can try this instead:

```js
let MyArray = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 4000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 2000
    }]
  }
]

const res = MyArray.map(obj => {
  const costInfo = obj.CostInfo.map(obj => {
    return { cost: obj.cost + 1000 };
  })
  return { ...obj, CostInfo: costInfo }
});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `itemToReplaceSecond`, not `item` (at the end of your `itemToReplaceFirst` declaration).

```js
let MyArray = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 4000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "CostInfo": [{
      "cost": 2000
    }]
  }
]

let itemToReplaceFirst = MyArray.map((item) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    CostInfo: item.CostInfo.map((innerItem) => {
      return {
        ...innerItem,
        cost: innerItem.cost + 1000
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(itemToReplaceFirst)
```

Comment: Need to doublecheck the output here, it doesn't match the input array

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the way your question was structured, it looks like you want to update the cost in a new array without modifying the original input array. This should accomplish that.

```js
let MyArray =  [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "CostInfo": [
      {"cost": 1000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 4000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 1000}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "CostInfo": [
        {"cost": 2000}
    ]
  }
]

const UpdatedArray = MyArray.map(item => {
  let updatedCostInfo = item.CostInfo.map(costinfo => {
    return { ...costinfo, cost: costinfo.cost + 1000}
  })

  return { ...item, CostInfo: updatedCostInfo }
});

console.log("Original Array: ", MyArray)
console.log("Updated Array: ", UpdatedArray)
```